# Customising color picker library

Tags: ios, objective-c, colors, color-picker

I want to create color pallet with specific colors by customizing color picker library . Recently I am using  [this](https://github.com/justinmeiners/ios-color-wheel) library and I can add custom colors to it but the problem is, it is showing lines when color is changing but I want to make it smooth. I have a screenshot for the Android here I am attaching it [Android White color pallet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu0Kz.png). For this Pallet We are entering HEXCode of colors in Warm-Color Library for Android.

I want to make same pallet as this, so suggest me if this kind of library is already available or how can I do it in Objective-C.

Comment: I have used [this](https://github.com/nakiostudio/NKOColorPickerView) in my app. This might help you. If any difficulty you face feel free to comment here. :)

Comment: Thanks @iPeter for the responce but it not looking same as I want.